Error installing codelite-plugins
gui@Latitude:~$ sudo apt-get install -y codelite-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codelite-plugins : Depends: codelite (= 14.0+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: cppcheck (>= 1.54) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libunittest++-dev but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: qt5-qmake but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: websocketpp-dev but it is not installable
                    Recommends: libasio-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

how can I solve this?

What did you do leading up to this? Is this still on Ubuntu 24.04? CodeLite 14 is provided in Ubuntu 22.04, you shouldn’t end up with that on 24.04...
